# Как из callbaсk-html взять нужные теги в JS?

Tags: javascript

В коллбеке приходит HTML.

```
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Ф.И.О."</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "E-Mail"</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Телефон"</font></p>
...
...
...
```

Нужно вырезать и сохранить в виде массива все теги с классом "errortext".

Типа функции preg_match_all в PHP.

Как это можно сделать в JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Регулярки тут не нужны. Разберите html, как html:

```js
let html = `
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Ф.И.О."</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "E-Mail"</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Телефон"</font></p>
`;

let dom = document.createElement('html');
dom.innerHTML = html;
let errors = Array.from(dom.querySelectorAll('.errortext'))
  .map(el => el.innerText);

console.log(errors)
```

*Таким образом, Вы во первых, избавляетесь от сложностей разбора html, во вторых у Вас есть полноценные DOM-элементы, которые, при необходимости, можно переносить/клонировать в документ.*

Answer (score 4):

[`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) в помощь:

```js
const htmlStr = `<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Ф.И.О."</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "E-Mail"</font></p>
<p><font class="errortext">Заполните поле "Телефон"</font></p>`; 

const parsed = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlStr, 'text/html');   // <-- магия вот тут
let elemArray = Array.from(parsed.querySelectorAll('.errortext')); 

elemArray.forEach(el => console.log(el.outerHTML));
```

Comment: Это даже лучше. Если не нужен IE9 =)

Comment: IE вообще не нужен, любой `:D` Ну, и Babel наверное осилит такой код...

Answer (score 1):

В соседних ответах могут возникнуть проблемы с невалидными фрагментами html.
Например, c частями таблиц - ячейками без строк и т.п.
В новых браузерах можно использовать элемент `<template>` для подобных фрагментов:

```
function parseHTML(html, context) {
    var t = (context || document).createElement('template');
        t.innerHTML = html;
    return t.content.cloneNode(true);
}
```

Для более широкой поддержки браузеров можно использовать наработки jQuery  в этой области: [gist @Munawwar](https://gist.github.com/Munawwar/6e6362dbdf77c7865a99)